# PHP preg_split Apache & Powershell equivalent

Tags: php, windows, linux, apache, powershell

### What Im Building:

The script archives a working directory using GIT-POSH and sends it to a Linux Apache Server using a Windows Powershell SSH Module.

For convenience, the script also needs to do reporting on existing files on the local machine as well as the Apache server.

### The Problem:

This is where I need string manipulation to separate each block in the naming convention.

I was going to use underscores `block_block` until I realized some of the blocks contain underscores them already.
This is when I decided to encapsulate each block with brackets `[block][block]`

> In PHP I would use preg_split to pull out each piece into an associative array.

```
[product][branch_name][date][time][commit_hash]
```

### Expected Usage:

```
--> Get-Product $string
--> product123
--> Get-Branch $string
--> branch123
```

### Questions I have:

- How do I `preg_split` this string the same way using powershell and apache?
- A better naming convention that supports the same operation?

Comment: Can you give some more info on what the input and expected output would be?

Comment: @MikeShepard Please see edits.

Comment: You can use the C# regex library, IMHO, which is what we did, to get preg_split behavior. Look at loading/using assemblies in powershell.

Comment: I see the edits, but you didn't say what the input was or what $string is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP's `preg_split` can be mimicked with `System.RegularExpressions.Split()`. There are some caveats, namely `Split()` will return empty strings for tokens it replaced, so some filtering is needed. Like so,

```
$data = "[product][branch_name][date][time][commit_hash]"
$arr = [Regex]::Split($data, "[\[\]]") | ? { $_.length -gt 0 }
$arr
```

Output:

```
product
branch_name
date
time
commit_hash
```

Without the filtering clause `? { $_.length -gt 0 }` - which will exclude string objects that have length of zero - the output would be slightly different:

```
product

branch_name

date

time

commit_hash
```

This behaivour [is documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) in MSDN.